# Transformations are not getting applied to SVGs in Glide 4+

Tags: android, svg, android-glide

I am using Glide 4.9.0 to load SVGs and JPGs. I recently migrated to 4+.

```
private RequestBuilder<PictureDrawable> requestBuilder;

requestBuilder = GlideApp.with(this)
                .as(PictureDrawable.class)
                .listener(new SvgSoftwareLayerSetter());

requestBuilder.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.kj_merch_default)
                        .load(uri)
                        .transform(new RoundedCorners(20))
                        .into((merchimage));
```

My Uri is a SVG. Image is showing properly but the `new RoundedCorners(20)` are not getting applied.

Does Glide Support SVGs Transformations?